# try to loading part of a webpage with ajax,without blocking the entire page.how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I tried to loading a particular part of web page with ajax.But the entire web page is stucked.I cant do any operations or clicks within the page.css for div and code is given below:

```
$(".tree-loader").show();
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "toolsList.htm",
        success : function(item) {
            jsd = JSON.parse(item);
            $("#treeA").remove();
            $(".tools-workspace-div").append("<div id='treeA'></div>");
            drawTree(jsd.data);
            $("#externaldrop").val(JSON.stringify(jsd.data));
            treeFunctionalities(jsd.data);
            $("#filter").val('');
            $(".tree-loader").hide();
//          $(".tree-loader").modal("hide");
            $("#treeA").on('contextmenu', function (e) {
                return false;
            });
        },
        error : function(){
            alert("Error in getting tools list");
            $(".tree-loader").hide();
//          $(".tree-loader").modal("hide");
        }
    });

.tree-loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 90%;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    /* width: 100%;
    height: 100%; */
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background: url('resources/images/Preloader_5.gif') 50% 40% no-repeat; 
    /* background: url('resources/images/spinner1.gif') 50% 40% no-repeat; */
}
```

Comment: You need to debug it a bit more, and/or show us some more code - we can't see any of the functions you call from the "success" callback. Maybe, just for instance, `drawTree(jsd.data);` contains an infinite loop or something. Just a guess but it's the kind of thing which could happen. Set breakpoints in your JS code to see where it reaches, and whether it progresses the AJAX request, whether it gets a response, what it does after that, whether the console shows any errors or warnings etc. We can't do any of that for you. If you're still stuck after that, report your findings here.

Comment: there is no error.my problem is ,i cant do any operations inside the page only after loading the particular part of web page..during the loading time,web page stucked

Comment: Yes I understand that. I'm telling you that _you_ need to go and find out why, by doing proper debugging of your JavaScript code. Do you understand how to do that? If not, now would be an excellent time to learn. Unfortunately in this particular case we cannot tell you the problem just by looking at the code, or at least not by looking at the code you have provided so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is as you quoted, then you mixed your CSS code with your JS code. It this is inside a script, then you will get an error. You will need to move your CSS code into an external css file or into a style tag.

Your JS code sends a request to the server and parses the response. You did not share all the functions you are using there, so it is possible that they are running forever for some reason. Such a reason might be a cycle in your graph, which is assumed to be a tree.

EDIT

From the comment section it became clear that there is no infinite cycle, but a very very long task to be executed.

Javascript is single-threaded with the exception of worker threads, but more on them later.

How to cope with a very very slow code? There are actually many solutions.

#### Optimize the code

Debug the code and find out which part is the bottleneck and see whether you can improve its speed in any way. This should be the first thing you do, before anything else and if this solves your problem, then you would not need to do anything else.

#### Execute this on server-side

You can implement the same logic you wanted to be executed on the server-side and send an [AJAX request](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) to tell the server you need it to do this job for you and asynchronously wait for the eventual response. Since the task is executed on the server, your browser will no longer be responsive and will gracefully wait for the server's response.

However, this is not always feasible. Since the task takes so long, this could easily make your server unresponsive, if many browsers are asking for the same complex thing at virtually the same time. So, this is a possible solution, but you will need to think about your exact problem and decide whether this solution is good for this problem, or not.

#### Pause the task periodically

Let's consider this prototype:

```
function TaskManager(t) {
    var tasks = [];    

    function Task(params) {
        //initialize your task
        this.execute = (() => {
            //Execute the task somehow
        });
    }

    this.addTask = ((params) => {
        tasks.push(new Task(params));
    });

    this.execute = (() => {
        this.index = 0;
        this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
            tasks[this.index++].execute();
            if (this.index === tasks.length) {
                clearInterval(this.intervalID);
                this.finalize();
            }
        }, t);
    });

    this.finalize = (() => {
        //Do something
    });
}
```

This should be perfectly able to solve your problem, but you will need to rephrase your problem, to change it from being one big single task into being a set of small tasks. `t` is the number of milliseconds you want your browser to wait between two chunks. If `t` is large-enough, then your browser will be responsive. But if it is too large, then your task will be finished later. Example:

```
function TaskManager(t) {
    var tasks = [];    

    function Task(params) {
        //initialize your task
        this.execute = (() => {
            console.log(new Date());
        });
    }

    this.addTask = ((params) => {
        tasks.push(new Task(params));
    });

    this.execute = (() => {
        this.index = 0;
        this.intervalID = setInterval(() => {
            tasks[this.index++].execute();
            if (this.index === tasks.length) {
                clearInterval(this.intervalID);
                this.finalize();
            }
        }, t);
    });

    this.finalize = (() => {
        console.log('finished');
    });
}

var tm = new TaskManager(100);

for (var i = 0; i < 3000; i++) tm.addTask({});

tm.execute();
```

#### Web Workers

In some [modern browsers](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) you can use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), which will work as separate threads, this is effectively what you were looking for. However, they are not available everywhere. If you are okay with supporting only modern browsers which support Web Workers, then this solution is for you.

#### Hybrid solution

You try to work with Web Workers so your task will run in the background and if they are not available, use the periodical pause approach as a fallback:

```
if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    // Yes! Web worker support!
    // Execute your task in the background
} else {
    // Execute your task with pauses
}
```

This elegant solution is very attractive in my opinion.

Comment: CSS code is in separate css file.not mixed like as I quoted.

Comment: @SnehaNair I understand. What is the problem you are experiencing? Is your browser becoming unresponsive? Do you get any errors in your Dev Tools console?

Comment: there is no error in console.but browser become unresponsive.cant do other operations like button click,page redirect etc..its possible only after loading that particular part completed

Comment: @SnehaNair I understand. Now. Can you run the code with a debugger and see what is being executed forever? Hot candidates are drawTree and treeFunctionalities. You should simply put a breakpoint at the start of this function and step over each line until it is being executed forever.

Comment: already put debugger in each functions.i tested it through each lines.no function exceuted forever..within minutes loading completed..but in that time web page is unresponsive..

Comment: @SnehaNair put a single breakpoint only at the start of your success callback. There should be the bottleneck. If you have an infinite cycle, then you should experience it there.

Comment: @SnehaNair ".within minutes loading completed"... so from that statement it sounds like the code is not "stuck" (as in failing to execute, or looping forever), it's just simply that the processing takes a very long time? JavaScript is single-threaded so it's expected that if some JS code is taking a long time, nothing else will be functional. I suggest you either find a way to make your code more efficient, or perhaps investigate whether you can do some/all of this processing on the server-side and send the result ready-made to the browser.

Comment: Did you mean if the process takes lots of time,it will affect the the entire webpage even if i tried to load a particular part?

Comment: Also only after completing the processing,even if it is taken less or more time the web page become responsive?

Comment: problem with using the webpage at the same time,loading(part of page)takes place.Isn't possible??

Comment: If processing time is less,is it possible to use the web page even if loading part of webpage take place.

Comment: @ADyson actually, Web Workers are running in the background for the browsers which support them.

Comment: @LajosArpad only if that's how you implement your code...since we can't see it, we can't assume that they have been used in this case. But using that concept to solve the problem is a good one, provided OP can choose only to support those browsers which can use them

Comment: @SnehaNair "Did you mean if the process takes lots of time,it will affect the the entire webpage even if i tried to load a particular part? "...yes exactly. There is, by default, only one processing thread for code, events etc, so if JS code is running, then nothing else can happen, unless that code is something which is naturally asynchronous (e.g. ajax requests) or using web workers etc as outlined in this answer

Comment: @ADyson actually the user can choose a hybrid approach to use Web Workers where they are supported and use a fallback logic for browsers which are not supporting this feature, as pointed out in my edited answer. The fallback logic to be used in case Web Workers are not supported could be a logic which divides the task into smaller chunks and executes them with pauses, using setInterval.

Comment: @ADyson :If processing time is less,is it possible to use the web page even if loading part of webpage take place?

Comment: @SnehaNair No matter how long the processing takes, the website will be un-usable for that length of time - whether it's 1 second or 100 seconds.

Comment: @LajosArpad:Javascript is single-threaded with the exception of worker threads, but more on them later.can u explain more about this?Is there any relevant links related to this?

Comment: @SnehaNair I have already explained it. Take a look at my answer, particularly at the Web Workers section where two links are given.